# Laravel 5.4 FatalException

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build a social network with Laravel everything is good except one thing.. everytime i hit the submit button he insert in the database but i get the same error

((1/1) FatalErrorException 
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Profile' not found in RegisterController.php (line 84) )

I moved on the file Profile .php in the same directory but everytime i get an error please help!! here's the code :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{


use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
  protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'gender' => 'required|bool'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    if($data['gender'])
    {
        $avatar = 'public/defaults/avatars/male.jpg';
    }
    else
    {
        $avatar = 'public/defaults/avatars/female.png';
    }
    $user =  User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'gender' => $data['gender'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'slug' => str_slug($data['name']),
        'avatar' => $avatar
    ]);

    Profile::create(['user_id' => $user->id ]);
    return $user;
}
 }
```

User.php :

```
<?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

  class User extends Authenticatable
 {
   use Notifiable;

  /**
    * The attributes that are mass assignable.
    *
    * @var array
    */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password','slug','gender','avatar'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

}

Comment: You need to import your `Profile` model in `RegisterController` `use App\Profile`

Answer (score 0):

under your `RegisterController` add `App/Profile:`

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

```
use App\User;
use App\Profile;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
.......
```